# maven : UnknownHostException: repo.maven.apache.org

Tags: java, apache, maven

I am having this maven problem :

> [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:129)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:142)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:261)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:185)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:152)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:139)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:116)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:129)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(BuilderCommon.java:92)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
>   Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
>       at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:296)
>       at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:186)
>       at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:279)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:115)
>       ... 25 more
>   Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
>       at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
>       at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
>       at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:193)
>       at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:281)
>       ... 28 more
>   Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
>       at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:951)
>       at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:939)
>       at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:669)
>       at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: repo.maven.apache.org
>       at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:567)
>       at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
>       at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
>       at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
>       at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:601)
>       ... 4 more
>   Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: repo.maven.apache.org
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:175)
>       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:385)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:495)
>       at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:392)
>       at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:266)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:80)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:122)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
>       at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:446)
>       at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:561)
>       ... 8 more

I do have an internet connection. and I am not behind a proxy.

Comment: Are you sure the groupid, artifact id and version are all correct? Did you use http://mvnrepository.com/ to copy and paste the dependency?

Comment: Can you ping the host from the command line?

Comment: ping  repo.maven.apache.org gives me "unknown host repo.maven.apache.org" but I am sure I have an internet connection otherwise I could not write this comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was my Internet provider's fault: their DNS server could not resolve `repo.maven.apache.org`. I switched to a 3G Internet connection. It worked and the ping returns a response.

Comment:  that's quite disturbing